# Invalid security token when login into webapp

Tags: php, curl

I'm making a curl script to test a web application, but when it logs in it gives me a page which says "Invalid security token!".

This is my code:

```
<?php

$username = '008C108';
$password = '8706405';

$loginUrl = 'http://localhost/ASTechOLE/login.php';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//login
$store = curl_exec($ch);



echo $store;
?>
```

I'm very new to curl so I don't really know how to take this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the form contains a token to prevent XSRF - so you will have to get the page that contains the form via cURL first, parse the token value out of it somehow, and then send that token value together with the rest of your data in the next request.

Comment: @04FS How can I parse the form page if I'm not logged in?

Comment: Make a GET request first, to get the HTML code of that page containing the initial form. As for how to get the token value out of that - depends on the specifics, but probably easiest using a small regular expression, targeting the specific field via ID or similar.

Answer (score -1):

I think your application needs API token or something like that.
Please see  [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) and [Token](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/Europe/events/foaf-galway/papers/fp/token_based_authentication/)
After that, you should put token inside your curl.